# Zip a whole folder using PHP exclude some subdirectory

Tags: php, zip

How do i Zip a whole folder with `PHP`?

```
// Get real path for our folder
$rootPath = realpath('folder-to-zip');

// Initialize archive object
$zip = new ZipArchive();
$zip->open('file.zip', ZipArchive::CREATE | ZipArchive::OVERWRITE);

// Create recursive directory iterator
/** @var SplFileInfo[] $files */
$files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($rootPath),
    RecursiveIteratorIterator::LEAVES_ONLY
);

foreach ($files as $name => $file)
{
    // Skip directories (they would be added automatically)
    if (!$file->isDir())
    {
        // Get real and relative path for current file
        $filePath = $file->getRealPath();
        $relativePath = substr($filePath, strlen($rootPath) + 1);

        // Add current file to archive
        $zip->addFile($filePath, $relativePath);
    }
}

// Zip archive will be created only after closing object
$zip->close();
```

I already tried this one and it works well, but i need to exclude some subdirectory, how can i do it?

That code will zip all files inside my directory, 
Example :

```
Main Folder
 -folder A
 -folder B
 -folder C
  -upload
   -data a
   -data b
   -data c
```

I want to zip all of this, but exclude "data b" and "data c"

I change the foreach like this, but it still zip all the file

```
foreach ($files as $name => $file){
        if (!$file->isDir()){
            $filePath = $file->getRealPath();
            $relativePath = substr($filePath, strlen($rootPath) + 1);
            $get_id_directory = strpos($relativePath,$view_id_noSpace);
            $get_upload_directory = strpos($relativePath,'upload');
            $zip->addFile($filePath, $relativePath);

            if($get_upload_directory != ''){
                if($get_id_directory == ''){
                    //$zip->addFile($filePath, $relativePath);
                    $zip->deleteName($filePath, $relativePath);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: please show us what you have already tried. Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @MagnusEriksson i already updated the question, hope you can understand it ^^ Thank you

Comment: The problem isn't that I don't understand your question. The problem is that it doesn't contain a minimal, complete and verifiable example. It doesn't contain any example at all. Please read the links I posted and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson okay! Thanks ^^

Answer (score -1):

The actual command is:

```
zip -r myarchive.zip dir1 -x dir1/ignoreDir1/**\* dir1/ignoreDir2/**\*
```

Here myarchive.zip is the name of zip file to be created.
dir1 is the folder which will be zipped.
ignoreDir1, ignoreDir2 are the folders that you do not want to include in the zip folder.

Comment: The OP is asking about doing it in PHP, not through the command line.